# C++ enum variable setting to more than one value

Tags: c++

I am trying to set more than one value to an enum variable, but I am currently facing a compilation error:

```cpp
main()
{
    typedef enum t_e {
        T_FIRST = 0x00,
        T_SECOND = 0x01,
        T_THIRD = 0x02,
    } t_t;

    t_t value = T_SECOND;
    value |= T_THIRD;
}
```

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘t_t {aka main()::t_e}’ [-fpermissive]
     value |= T_THIRD;
```

Could you please help? Is there any way I can achieve it?

Comment: Why the `typedef`?

Comment: You didn't provide a `t_t& operator|=(t_t& a, t_t b)` function.

Comment: An enum doesn't have a native compound assignment operator (`|=`)